# Presentation of SNEG creation and annihilation operators in Mathematica 11

Tags: packages, physics

I am using the Mathematica package SNEG to make some calculations in solid state physics (see http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/). The programs in SNEG library are running, but their presentation are poor. For example, if I define the bosonic operator $\beta$

In[2]:= snegbosonoperators[$\beta$];

I do find that a bosonic operator was defined considering the commutation relations

In[3]:= nc[$\beta$[AN, UP], $\beta$[CR, UP]] - 
 nc[$\beta$[CR, UP], $\beta$[AN, UP]]

Out[3]= 1

However, the SNEG is not displaying the common dagger symbols that are normally used in Physics and that appear in the program documentation, but something like this instead:

In[4]:= nc[ $\beta$[CR, i, UP], $\beta$[AN, i, UP]]

Out[4]=  $\beta$(0,i,1) $\cdot$ $\beta$(1,i,1).

This problem did not happen when I used Mathematica 9. Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Comment: I had no problem getting the operators typeset (with daggers and spin arrows) in version 11.3. Perhaps restarting Mathematica or reinstalling sneg might help.